# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Component

Tags: java, matlab

When I run MATLAB install script in Ubuntu, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Component
```

longer output is available [here](http://pastebin.com/4fgu56MV)

I know that it's a Java problem and could potentially be fixed by changing the classpath or something like that but I don't exactly know how.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to install remotely?

Comment: That's true. I ssh to the server that I have previously copied the contents of the MATLAB DVD to. Then I run install script on the server.

Comment: There you go then - it's trying to run the GUI installer (via Java) but it can't instantiate anything because there's no display. Try to install it via command line only.

Comment: The thing is that I ssh with -X enabled. So I should have X.

Comment: How can I install without the GUI?

Comment: Maybe try with `-Y` instead. Re. installing from command line, I don't recall exactly at this moment but I found this blog post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120801/how-do-i-install-matlab-r2012a . Search around for some more on non-interactive install maybe. I think the gist is that you have to make a short config file.

Answer (score 7):

For me this error was fixed when I installed the JRE on my system:

```
apt-get install default-jre
```

on Ubuntu 12.04, instead of having MATLAB use its own.

Comment: Worked for me. I tired other stuff first. Surely I didnt need all of it, never mind.

Comment: 7 years later, this worked for me. After 3 hours of pulling my hair.

Answer (score 2):

I've been battling this problem for the whole evening as well but I stumbled onto a solution that works for me at least.

After trying to install using the silent installer I got a different error with a bit more information. It turned out that a library was missing (libXtst.so.6). I was able to install that on my Ubuntu system with:

```
apt-get install libxtst6
```

After that I tried running the GUI installer (over X forwarding) and it looks like it's going to work now.

Answer (score 1):

For MATLAB R2012a Student Edition, in Ubuntu 14.04, I had to install these prerequisites first:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre libxtst6:i386 libXext6:i386 libxi6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libxt6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxp6:i386
```

Next I installed/activated per MATLAB's instructions (`sudo ./install`). I answered "yes" when the installer asked to add a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin/

Finally, when launching MATLAB, I have to specify that it run in 32-bit mode:

```
matlab -glnx86
```

I assembled those steps from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/363878/how-to-install-32-bit-matlab-in-ubuntu-64-bit

and the Ubuntu MATLAB guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

#### Optional

I didn't want to type the -glnx86 option each time I launch MATLAB, so I replaced the matlab symbolic link in /usr/local/bin/ with a script that automatically specifies the -glnx86 option:

```sh
ls -l /usr/local/bin/matlab #note the destination of the symbolic link
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/matlab.bak
#ensure the first path below matches your symbolic link's destination
echo '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/bin/matlab -glnx86  "$@"' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/matlab
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/matlab
```

With that, I can type 'matlab' and it launches properly. (The `"$@"` in the script forwards all input arguments to matlab.) There's probably a more elegant way to accomplish this, but it worked.

I also encountered a "/lib/libc.so.6: not found" error on matlab startup, which I fixed by following [this answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95976-why-do-i-get-a-libc-so-6-not-found-error-when-launching-matlab-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Installing gnome (sudo apt-get install gnome) fixed this problem for me.  I'm sure this was total overkill, but the required libraries are now available.